# pgi cuda fortran compiling error

Tags: cuda, compiler-errors, fortran

As I compile a single cuda fortran code , the compiler  give me the following error, 
PGF90-F-0000-Internal compiler error. Device compiler exited with error status code    and 
Attempt to call global subroutine without chevrons: increment

arch linux, pgf90 2013
the code is as follow:

```
module simple
contains
  attributes (global) subroutine increment(a,b)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(inout) :: a(:)
    integer , intent(in) :: b
    integer :: i , n
    n = size( a )
    do i = 1 , n
       a ( i ) = a ( i )+ b
    end do
  end subroutine increment
end module simple


program incrementTestCPU
  use simple
  implicit none
  integer  :: n = 256
  integer :: a ( n ) , b
  a = 1
  b = 3
  call increment ( a , b )
  if ( any ( a /= 4)) then
     write (* ,*) "pass"
  else
     write(*,*) "not passed"
  end if
end program incrementTestCPU
```

Comment: So you have an internal compiler error, which is by definition a bug in the compiler.  What is your question?

Comment: how can I compile the code? the only way is to buy another version ?

Comment: CUDA is quite new, it is not surprising that a two-year old compiler version has bugs in that field.  A newer compiler version might work, or it might not; you might want to contact the vendor to find out. How you can get a new version depends on your support/upgrade situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be something only vendor support channels can answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling this a "cuda fortran" code, but it is syntactically incorrect whether you want to ultimately run the subroutine on the host (CPU) or device (GPU).  You may wish to refer to this [blog post](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/easy-introduction-cuda-fortran/) as a quick start guide.

If you want to run the subroutine `increment` on the GPU, you have not called it correctly:

call increment ( a , b )

A GPU subroutine call needs kernel launch parameters, which are contained in the "triple chevron" `<<<...>>>` syntax which should be placed between the `increment` and its parameter list, like so:

```
call increment<<<1,1>>> ( a , b )
```

and this is giving rise to the error message:

> Attempt to call global subroutine without chevrons

If, instead, you intend to run this subroutine on the CPU, and are just passing it through the CUDA fortran compiler, then it is incorrect to specify the `global` attribute on the subroutine:

```
attributes (global) subroutine increment(a,b)
```

The following is a modification of your code which would run the subroutine on the GPU, and compiles cleanly for me with PGI 14.9 tools:

```
$ cat test3.cuf
module simple
contains
  attributes (global) subroutine increment(a,b)
    implicit none
    integer :: a(:)
    integer, value :: b
    integer :: i , n
    n = size( a )
    do i = 1 , n
       a ( i ) = a ( i )+ b
    end do
  end subroutine increment
end module simple


program incrementTestCPU
  use simple
  use cudafor
  implicit none
  integer, parameter  :: n = 256
  integer, device :: a_d(n), b_d
  integer :: a ( n ) , b
  a = 1
  b = 3
  a_d = a
  b_d = b
  call increment<<<1,1>>> ( a_d , b_d )
  a = a_d
  if ( any ( a /= 4)) then
     write (* ,*) "pass"
  else
     write(*,*) "not passed"
  end if
end program incrementTestCPU

$ pgf90 -Mcuda -ta=nvidia,cc20,cuda6.5 -Minfo test3.cuf -o test3
incrementtestcpu:
     23, Memory set idiom, loop replaced by call to __c_mset4
     29, any reduction inlined
$ pgf90 --version

pgf90 14.9-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp nehalem
The Portland Group - PGI Compilers and Tools
Copyright (c) 2014, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.
$
```

If you are trying to create a CPU-only version, then remove *all* CUDA Fortran syntax from your program.  If you still have difficulty, you can ask a Fortran-directed question, as it is not a CUDA issue at that point.  As an example, the following (non-CUDA) code compiled cleanly for me:

```
module simple
contains
  subroutine increment(a,b)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(inout) :: a(:)
    integer , intent(in) :: b
    integer :: i , n
    n = size( a )
    do i = 1 , n
       a ( i ) = a ( i )+ b
    end do
  end subroutine increment
end module simple


program incrementTestCPU
  use simple
  implicit none
  integer, parameter  :: n = 256
  integer :: a ( n ) , b
  a = 1
  b = 3
  call increment ( a , b )
  if ( any ( a /= 4)) then
     write (* ,*) "pass"
  else
     write(*,*) "not passed"
  end if
end program incrementTestCPU
```