# high order number in computer simulation

Tags: fortran, numerical, pde

I wrote a Fortran code to solve PDE (like continuity equation) but the initial 
value of unknown are in order of 1.0e20 this imply my code to give NANE (not number) of infinity because it's multiplying or dividing big number 
what can I do to run simulation with such big number?
the equation are : Poisson equation and continuity  like equations

Comment: I search for some math technique to maybe normalize the equation and I wonder if such technique can be used or not!

Comment: What physical units are you using?

Comment: si(vol, meter, colon, vol/meter)

Comment: It is usually recommended to use physical (or reduced) units with which various quantities become on the order of 1. But I guess if you use double precision (64bit), things will go okay although huge values play around in your program :)

Comment: Please see, for example, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187291/which-units-should-i-use-in-molecular-dynamics-simulation

Comment: non-native extended precision numerics will significantly impair performance. You should work hard to normalise your system to avoid the large numbers before turning to such brute force approach. Voting to close for lack of details.

Comment: I believe it will be more fruitful to post the question (with explicit equations) in Physics or Computational Science rather than SO Fortran http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129712/is-there-a-normalized-form-of-the-euler-equation-discretized-with-finite-volumes

Comment: Also in a new post it should be very helpful to mention CUDA (if necessary, just my guess) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309241/pgi-cuda-fortran-compiling-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extended precision`, `real*8`, or `double precision` (which are a 64-bit floating point representations) as the type instead of `real` (which is 32 bits).  That will give an exponent range of at least 308 instead of the smaller range of 38.

Comment: `double precision` surely?  Although that doesn't offer the guarantees you mention.

Comment: @francescalus:  `double precision` is another synonyn.  `extended precision` comes from the off-brand Fortran I used in the 1970s.  Unless the computer is not using IEEE-754 representations, the 308 range is a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: thanks for reply, I search for math technique not using real*8 (double precision)